# How to access PHP functions from other pages?

Tags: php, sql, function

This is the code I have in a separate file called dbinterface.php.

```
<?php

include("dbconnect.php");

function delFruit($fruitID) {
# Deleting a fruit- will automatically delete all inventory relating to that fruit    
due to DB reactions on table
    $sql = "DELETE FROM FRUIT WHERE ID = '$fruitID'";
    return execSQL($sql);
}
```

and the dbconnect.php file is as follows:

```
<?php

try {
   $dbh = new PDO("sqlite:sqlite.db"); 
}
catch(PDOException $e) {
    echo $e->getMessage();
}
```

Also, there is a database file called sqlite.db.  My question is, if I need to use one of the functions in the file called dbinterface, how can I access the function and execute it? I would like to write some SELECT functions and execute them in various other PHP pages for display. Any idea on how I can do this? I'm new to PHP...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

add `include("dbinterface.php");` in the page you want to use a function from it.

After the file is included, the functions will be placed in the global scope.

Comment: Okay, so, say I wanted to get the result from a SELECT statement and echo it to html? Also, do you know how to get string values from SELECT statements, or would it just do that automatically?

Comment: You will get the query result exactly how you are getting if the function is used on the same page. see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13173426/how-to-call-sql-statements-from-a-php-function

Comment: Could you tell me how I can execute a function from an included file in another document?